# Codeigniter 2.1, MySQL - search by date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In my DB I have **date** field with a standard **datetime** for MySQL **(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)**. Trough AJAX request I am getting this time: **DD/MM/YYYY**

This is the function I had written to search trough DB:

```
$this->db->get_where('tvprogram', array('DATE(date)' => $date))->result_array();
```

At the moment this function isn't getting any data. What seems to be wrong here? How can I search and find all entries for specific day?

Answer (score 3):

Use `strtotime` function  to convert the date to correct format:

```
 $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
 $this->db->get_where('tvprogram', array('DATE(date)' => $date))->result_array();
```

Comment: Do you mean `$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));` or is MySQL clever enough to strip out the time portion of the timestamp?

Comment: Your function is working, but I needed to delete **H:i:s** part. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: oops!!! yes... forgot about that.. :)..(thought i was comparing with other dates in php... damn!!!! i have to go for coffee now :) :)..) updated ... anyways glad it helped.. welcome and happy coding...:)

Comment: @MarcAudet ...yes updated.. added that extra H:i:s which is not required at all... thanks...:)....

Comment: See my comment below regarding the European/American date convention.

Answer (score 0):

Please convert first posted date in database format and use with Date function in your searching field like this.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($search));
$this->db->where('DATE(created)',$date);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the format coming out of `DATE(date)` because it is probably like YYYY-MM-DD and the comparison will always fail.

Go into phpMyAdmin or similar and try `SELECT DATE(now())` and double check the date format.

If `$date` has a format like `DD/MM/YYY`, then you can reformat it by using:

```
$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(strtr($date,"/","-")));
```

From the PHP manual (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator        between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

To fix the American/European date ambiguity, I simply replace "/" with "-" before the string to time conversion.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment, not as an answer as it is just debugging steps, and not a solution to the question.